# Using guava's MapConstraint on a somehow synchronized Map

Tags: java, dictionary, synchronization, guava

Using Guava, I would like to have a map that has the following properties:

- A lot of reads, but very few writes.
- the data doesn't expire.
- must be synchronized, so a write is "atomic" and multiple reads don't interfere with each other.
- the map should use the `MapConstraint` API and a few of these `MapConstraint` are against the content of the map itself (typically if the records or another exists, do not overwrite it: throw an `IllegalStateException` instead). I see that the `MapConstraint` interface doesn't give the `Map` being constrained.
- the `MapConstraint`'s check must be done inside the synchronization part.

I've well thought about using a `ReadWriteLock`, but I'm wondering if the `MapMaker` can help me here since I'm not very familiar with that API.

So what are my options?

---

Edit: My goal is not a simple `putIfAbsent`: I need to perform several checks against the map before inserting the value, always in the synchronized write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can do this easily with the **MapConstraint** semantics. You *could* make the MapConstraint aware of the underlying map, by passing it a reference to the map during construction:

```
MapConstraints.constrainedMap(map, new MyCustomMapConstraint(map));
```

But it would be ugly / risky. Somebody could erroneously do:

```
MapConstraint constraint = new MyCustomMapConstraint(firstMap);
Map constrainedMap = MapConstraints.constrainedMap(secondMap, constraint);
```

Plus, it wouldn't solve the synchronization problem.

---

If I were to do this, I would use the "putIfAbsent" method provided by ConcurrentMap. I would create a ConcurrentMap wrapper using ForwardingConcurrentMap:

```
public class ProtectionistMap<K, V> extends ForwardingConcurrentMap<K, V> {

    private final ConcurrentMap<K, V> delegate;

    public ProtectionistMap(ConcurrentMap<K, V> delegate) {
        this.delegate = checkNotNull(delegate);
    }

    @Override
    protected ConcurrentMap<K, V> delegate() {
        return delegate;
    }

    @Override
    public V put(K key, V value) {
        V result = putIfAbsent(key, value);

        // The second part of the test is necessary when a map may contain null values...
        if (result != null || value == null && containsKey(key)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Map already had an entry for key " + key);
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public void putAll(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> map) {
        standardPutAll(map);
    }
}
```

Comment: I like the idea of the FCM, but I don't really like the fact that I have to re-manage the synchronization myself. However since there isn't a `MapConstraints` method for `ConcurrentMap`, I guess I'm up to do the synchronization myself.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is not about Guava at all, but why not to consider use of java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap? It has all you need apart from direct support for MapConstraint.

If records exists you can just use containsKey() method, instead of throwing exception. 
Or if you need an exception just create your own class inherited from the ConcurrentHashMap. It can also use MapConstraint, if you really need it.
Looks like 2 mins jobs, the code will look like this:

```
public V put(K key, V value) {
    if (value == null)
        throw new NullPointerException();
    int hash = hash(key.hashCode());
    Segment seg = segmentFor(hash);
    V result;
    seg.lock()
    try {
        constraint.checkKeyValue(key, value);
        v = seg.put(key, hash, value, false)
    } finally {
        seg.unlock()
    }
    return result;
}
```

Don't take that code literally, that's just an example ;)

If you need more info about ConcurrentHashMap internals, you can have a look here:
[ConcurrentHashMap revealed](http://stas-blogspot.blogspot.com/2010/08/concurrenthashmap-revealed.html)

Comment: Well in fact, `MapMaker` builds `ConcurrentMap` s. So all in all, it would come back to what you suggest, except done with more flexibility. Thanks for the suggestion anyway and for the link!